# Sending HTML(including attributes) from python to webpage using flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I have a rather peculiar problem here and I have no idea why this problem should occur.
I have a form on a page which takes input and python processes that input and displays the output on the same page.
I had some problems in making this work but all of it works now. To make it look better I tried to make it so that the output comes in a terminal-like window using [termynal.js](https://github.com/ines/termynal). It's rather simple but I am not getting the desired output.

### Snippets of code:

**Variable I'm returning from app.py**

```
# This is not multi-line, I just made it so for easy readability
final = "<span data-ty=\"input\">CMS Name</span>
         <span data-ty=\"progress\"></span>
         <span data-ty>" + cms2 + "</span>
         <span data-ty=\"input\">IP Address</span>
         <span data-ty=\"progress\"></span>
         <span data-ty>"+ip+"</span>
         <span data-ty=\"input\">Scanning for open ports...</span>
         <span data-ty=\"progress\"></span>
         <span data-ty=\"input\">Scanning Website...</span>
         <span data-ty=\"progress\"></span>"

return jsonify(result = final)
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/termynal.js')}}" data-termynal-container="#termynal"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
   $(function() {
        $('a#baseButton').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/result', {
            website: $('input[name="website"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
           $("#termynal").html(data.result);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainBox" id="termynal" data-termynal data-ty-typeDelay="40" data-ty-lineDelay="700">
</div>
</body>
```

## EDIT 1

I added `print final` before returning it and this is what I got, which seems perfectly right to me

```
<span data-ty="input">CMS Name</span><span data-ty="progress"></span><span data-ty>Joomla</span><span data-ty="input">IP Address</span><span data-ty="progress"></span><span data-ty>104.26.4.173</span><span data-ty="input">Scanning for open ports...</span><span data-ty="progress"></span><span data-ty ></span><span data-ty="input">Scanning Website...</span><span data-ty="progress"></span>
```

So I'm stumped.

## EDIT 2 : Adding Screenshots

So I pasted the above obtained value of `final` in codepen(link here: [CodePen Test](https://codepen.io/kshitij-tripathi/pen/JjjeMLq)

and here's what it looks like on my screen:
[image: Screen Output]

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the `final` text in triple quotes `"""   content """` as it is a multiline string.

Comment: wouldn't that just hardcode my variables alongwith the strings?